# SMTP configures by SES aws is going to spam folder

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

We have configured a smtp with SES service of aws.
we have also added DKIM for the service.

Our Reputation Dashboard shows:
[image]

But still our mails are hitting spam folder. We were previously using gmail smtp and it was working fine.

Could anyone suggest why this could be happening?

[image: ![enter image description here]

Will this do ?

Comment: I am not an expert. But i think it might help to set up a "MAIL FROM Domain". You are already doing DKIM. you can also set up custom "MAIL FROM Domain" as well. If you use Route53 to manage your domain, it will create MX and TXT records. the txt record is to setup spf record. you can give this a try https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/mail-from.html?icmpid=docs_ses_console

Comment: @ArunK i am already using Mail from Domain have those records as well in Route53 :).

Comment: Not sure then. Is it happening for everybody. The only other thing i can think of is to request a dedicated IP address for SES.

Comment: @ArunK we will pretty much over shoot our budget on that

Comment: Also I can't confirm that it will help

Comment: Did you setup an SPF record @sumanthshetty?

Comment: No I haven't . we have DKIM so @ChrisWilliams

Comment: @sumanthshetty you should use both, DKIM enhances what SPF is doing by signing any emails you send. However SPF allows mail exchanges to trust the source of where it was sent from.

Comment: @ChrisWilliams how would i add SPF Type record. 
What name and value should i give and which routing policies should i choose ?

Comment: and i have a TXT record type in my route53 @ChrisWilliams

Comment: Thats fine, if you already have a text record for your route domain in value just append another line with the value `"v=spf1 include:amazonses.com ~all"` underneath the other value(s)

Comment: @ChrisWilliams , I have just edited the question have added an image. 
Hope i am following you right i have added the value "v=spf1 include:amazonses.com ~all"  within the values of TXT record

Comment: The SPF record should be added to a text record on the root of the domain (no subdomain) as its not a AmazonSES specific record

Comment: @ChrisWilliams I don't have Test record for the root domain i have only MX record.
Should i add the Text record with these values for root domain ?

Comment: For the SPF record only, yes make it if you don't already have one.

Comment: @ChrisWilliams i have created a SPF record for the domain with ""v=spf1 include:amazonses.com ~all"" value having simple routing.

Comment: One last thing, this should be a `TXT` record ( I know its confusing), the type is not SPF (this is contained in the value). Other than that its perfect :)

Comment: @ChrisWilliams Have changed the SPF to TXT type. Hoping i am good now :)

Comment: OK sure, added the answer of what to do. Let me know if you need anymore help :)

Answer (score 1):

Whilst you have DKIM this is only part of a solution, DKIM is actually used to sign your emails so that an email provider can be assured there was no tampering during the sending of the email.

You should also include an SPF record, this will provide the target mail exchanges with a record to say that sending an email from SES is to be trusted. With both of these in place your emails should not longer be marked as spam from a result of SES (after this it is purely reputation based).

For adding an SPF record for SES follow [this documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/send-email-authentication-spf.html) from Amazon.

Comment: The mail are still going to spam

Comment: Validation is now passing for this, unless the mail exchange has cached a record that does not exist it would purely be reputation at this point. Is it a specific domain having this go to the spam folder (they may now auto put this as a spam rule). Try another domain to validate

Comment: when i try and send a test email by selecting the domain. 
i am able to receive it in my main folder.

Could you also have a time to look at this 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63112120/error-while-trying-to-upload-file-into-s3-no-access-control-allow-origin-head

Comment: Currently we are owning only one domain. 
Basically if i understood your comment , you mean to say mail exchange might have cached the email from our particular domain which is moving it to spam?

Comment: I meant it might cache that theres no SPF record, or automate that its spam. IF you with another mail exchange receiving email as a test you can validate

Comment: I feel so underwhelmed that i am not able to follow what your trying to explain. 
Could you please simplify the testing part as i understood the caching scenario.

How can i test it ?

Comment: So if your domain `example.com` is sending emails to `foobar.com` and `test@foobar.com` is marking them as spam, try sending them to another domain `test@anotherdomain.com` and see if the scenario replicates

Comment: Understood :) thank you for the patience. Man i trouble you a lot :)

Comment: Haha its fine :)

Comment: need your help on this 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63117159/patch-method-with-lambda-integration-for-update-operation-on-unknown-number-of-p

Comment: Sure, was this question resolve or is it still open @sumanthshetty? :)

Comment: still open. 
have to check with different mail exchange. As i am  getting the test mail in my inbox and for others it is going to promotions or spam. 

WE have to try with different mail exchange other than GMAIL