# PATCH method with Lambda integration for update operation on unknown number of parameters

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, http, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have created a resource with PATCH method through API Gateway and have it integrated with Lambda and also have integrated proxy on it.

I have hard coded the scenario to update the table.
small snippet from the lambda function

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # reading query parameters to work on from api end point 
    supplierID = event['queryStringParameters']['supplierID']
    supplierName = event['queryStringParameters']['supplierName']
```

supplierID is the primary key of the table and i am trying to update the supplierName from the table.

In this above scenario i know what i have to update as i was trying to test the working.

Now i am wondering how can i do it when i don't know which filed i will get from the query parameter of the api request to update.

Table has 10 column ID being the primary key.

How can i store the unknown query parameter and operate a update on Postgresql RDS.

Or should i use any other method to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

IF you have a predefined number of query string parameters you could create a mapping function to convert/process the parameters inside `event['queryStringParameters']` to determine which column they would map to.

You would need to set a mandatory field which must be unique and would allow an update, if the ID was not specified you would return an error to the user.

If this is an unknown query string parameter there is no need to store it in your database. Instead return a message to the user and write to your log ([CloudWatch logs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/WhatIsCloudWatchLogs.html) in `JSON` format). If you output in a JSON format you can then report using [CloudWatch logs insights](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/AnalyzingLogData.html) to view occurrences (and even set an alarm).

On a sidenote, as this is an update it would preferential to use a `PUT` request not a `GET` request with query string parameters. Especially if the information might be sensitive.

Comment: i was implementing it event['queryStringParameters']

assigning it to a dictionary object. param= event['queryStringParameters'] 
confused on how to map it.

we have around supplierEmail, supplierID, supplierName in the  param object now. using python

And i am using PATCH request for update

Comment: OK, and a mapping would simply be a function that could loop through the parameters specified and say if its this parameter then its this column plus format it :)

Comment: could you please assign a chat room for this please. I have few questions regarding the query structure

Comment: Here you go: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218742/room-for-chris-williams-and-sumanth-shetty